# How to develop a Hello World file backed virtual disk kernel extension for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, virtual, disk

Any sample code would be highly appreciated. I tried a couple of days googling on this, but found nothing. I hope experts here can shed some lights.

I am very familar with virtual disk drivers on Windows and Linux, but very new on Mac. We need information on the plumbing IoKit.

I need something to mount a plain file to a Mac disk, similar to the builtin hidutil on mounting .dmg file.

Comment: Why not use MacFUSE or a derivative?  Are you implying there is a performance or other tradeoff?  If so, what would those be?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [macfuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). The wiki includes a number of example file systems.

Comment: Macfuse is user mode, I need a pure kernel mode impl

Comment: @huisinro Why kernel mode please?  Could you provide an overview of the potential benefits?  Thank you